# Multiply button cannot execute

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to multiply two numbers but the button cannot be execute and therefore the results cannot be displayed.

```js
function multiply(){
   let x = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);
   let y = parseInt(document.querySelector("#operator").value);
   let z = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value4").value);
   let calculate;
   
   if(y == "mul"){
    calculate= x * z;
   }
   document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = calculate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
          <input type="text" id="value1">
          <div id="operator">
          <button type="button" onclick="multiply()" id="mul">*</button>
          <button type="button" onclick="" id="value3">/</button>
          </div>
          <input type="text" id="value4" >
          =
          <input type="text" id="results">
          
         
        </form>
        
    </body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

I tried to multiply two numbers but the button cannot be execute and therefore the results cannot be displayed.

Comment: The button doesn't have `value="mul"`

Comment: `document.querySelector("#operator")` selects `<div id="operator">`. It doesn't have a value so `document.querySelector("#operator").value` won't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the `y` variable. You only call the `multiply()` function from the multiply button, so you don't need to check the value of anything to see if it's `mul`.

`document.getElementById("results")` is an input, not a div, so you need to assign to its `value` property, not `innerHTML`.

```js
function multiply(){
   let x = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);
   let z = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value4").value);
   let calculate = x * z;
   document.getElementById("results").value = calculate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
          <input type="text" id="value1">
          <div id="operator">
          <button type="button" onclick="multiply()" id="mul">*</button>
          <button type="button" onclick="" id="value3">/</button>
          </div>
          <input type="text" id="value4" >
          =
          <input type="text" id="results">
          
         
        </form>
        
    </body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

you converted 'y' variable to an integer so it never can be 'mul'.it should be:

```
   let y = document.querySelector("#operator").value;
```

Comment: That still won't work, since `#operator` doesn't have a value. There's nothing in the HTML with `value="mul"`

Comment: I thought that he defined 'mul'.

Comment: He has `id="mul"`.